# In a django view, how do I redirect a user to the login view if that don't belong to the object set?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I feel like this is really simple and I'm just missing it.

I have a very simple generic class based view detail.

When I do teh `get_object` I want to make sure that the `request.user` is in the set that belongs to the object. If not, redirect them to the login.

Here's my view:

```
class AwesomeDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    """
    An awesome detail
    """
    template_name = "awesomeness/detail.html"

    def get_object(self):
        awesomeness = ModelName.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if self.request.user in awesomeness.staff.all():
            return awesomness
        else:
            return redirect('account_login')
```

Staff is a many to many to users. What am I missing? The redirect isn't happening. It renders the template, but of course, awesomeness is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) was introduced in Django 1.9.

You define a `test_func` method to return `True/Fales` depending on whether the test passes.

If the user fails the test they will be redirected to `settings.LOGIN_URL` with a redirect field.

`UserPassesTestMixin` supports any of the fields for [AccessMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin).

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin


class AwesomeDetail(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    """
    An awesome detail
    """
    template_name = "awesomeness/detail.html"
    model = ModelName

    def test_func(self):
        if self.request.user in self.object.staff.all():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Do you need the LoginRequiredMixin as well? A user can't pass a test if they're not logged in (well, an anonymous user test, maybe).

Comment: I’m not sure how this is the accepted answer. Reading through the implementation of `UserPassesTestMixin`, the `test_func` is called before `self.object` is set, so this should fail with an exception. I feel this case does not belong to `UserPassesTestMixin` but rather to some hypothetical `ObjectPassesTestMixin`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very sure about this, but sounds like `get` method is the one you should work on:

```
class AwesomeDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    """
    An awesome detail
    """
    template_name = "awesomeness/detail.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if not self.request.user in self.object.staff.all():
            return redirect('account_login')
        else:
            return super(AwesomeDetail, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be for a view method? Not class?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. You are using class based view right?